# How do I dispose a Matrix Array in OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

To release the memory of OpenCVSharp.Mat objects, I use the ResourceTracker [according to the documentation](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp):

```
using (ResourcesTracker t = new ResourcesTracker())
{
    Mat finalMat = t.T(new Mat());
}
```

However this syntax does not seem to be valid for an array of Mats used like this:

```
Mat[] images = t.T(new Mat[length]);
```

This gives me an System.ArgumentNullException, "The value cannot be NULL".

I've tried calling the `.Dispose()` of the Array, but this does not seem to have an effect on memory.

I realize I can let garbage collection do the job, but I'd rather do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
for (int j = 0; j<i; j++)
            {
                images[j].Dispose();
            }
```

Didn't really change anything though, I don't quite understand why I don't need to dispose the items when they're an array instead of a single Mat item.

My memory leak came from using the stitcher method and not using `stitcher.Dispose();`